# Node connection failed | Devops | Chef-server | Chef-node

Tags: amazon-ec2, devops, chef-infra, bootstrapping

It is creating a node but not connecting it to the server. The code i am using to connect the chef-server to chef-node is as follows

```
 knife bootstrap 172.31.40.99 --ssh-user ec2-user --sudo -i node-key.pem -N node3
```

here `node-key.pem` is the key-pair downloaded at the time of creating the instance. And `172.31.40.99` is the private IP of the node. It throws error as below

```
Creating new node for node3
Connecting to 172.31.40.99
WARN: [SSH] PTY requested: stderr will be merged into stdout
The authenticity of host '172.31.40.99 ()' can't be established.
fingerprint is SHA256:wtD+XsN7kYjRJaMyMo9KJME4YYug+wJzpbmh7V/8uXg.

WARN: [SSH] PTY requested: stderr will be merged into stdout
WARN: [SSH] connection failed, terminating (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ec2-user@172.31.40.99>)
ERROR: Train::Transports::SSHFailed: SSH session could not be established
```

Please help!!

The node is in the same zone as server